# Tag for dissolution process?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there any tag for [dissolution](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dissolution) ([Dissolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissolution_(chemistry))) process? If not, can it be created?

Answer (score 5):

No. We have [solubility](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solubility), which should be enough.

But we do have a [bunch](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=dissolve) of questions on the topic, we can add it to them if we the community wants it.

Comment: I think solubility is enough, if we expand the wiki a little. Reworking a lot of questions to implement a tag that was not used before, just seems like a lot of effort for not much gain. (But if the OP is up for the challenge, then I would not object.)